# Issue with variable in Path

Tags: windows-7, path

Using Windows7, have a path issue
I have set the ENV variable ANT_HOME c:\ant
I add into the PATH:  ;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

When I do

```
echo %ANT_HOME%
```

I get: `C:\ant`    -- **This works fine**

But if I do

```
echo %PATH%
```

I do not get the ANT_HOME translated, I just get %ANT_HOME% as below

```
;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

Instead if I set the path as:  `;c:\ant\bin;`  -- It all works fine

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not have very advanced dependency resolution for environment variables. If you set a system environment variable, you can refer to it in a per-user environment variable and it will be expanded. Referring to another per-user variable from a per-user one (or referring to another system one from a new system one) does nothing special. Trying to figure out which variables depend on which others would get very complicated very fast.

If you really want your per-user `%PATH%` to include the expanded `%ANT_HOME%` variable, `%ANT_HOME%` would have to be a system environment variable. The easiest solution is probably to put the full path (not in variable form) of your directory into the `PATH`.

Further reading: [The hidden variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj853254.aspx) by Raymond Chen.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. My general understanding was the 'User Variables' get translated somehow. But maybe I have to set them as System Variables (the lower window).  But nonetheless question remains my ENV-variable is getting correctly translated in the cmd window but not the path. Is there any down side to setting System variables (its just my personal machine)

Comment: +1 fascinating.. an example with setx and cmd copy/pasted would make this answer even better , even clearer

Comment: @Sam-T The `ANT_HOME` variable is set to `C:\ant`, so `%ANT_HOME%` expands to that. The `PATH` variable, however, contains the literal text `%ANT_HOME%` because there is no fancy dependency resolution, and expanding `%PATH%` gives you what's literally inside that variable.

Comment: @Ben So how/where would one use the 'user variables'? Are 'other' programs able to resolve them?

Comment: @Sam-T The user variables are being expanded as intended. All programs can use them if they invoke environment variable expansion. For example, Windows Explorer uses the per-user `PATH` when you type something into the Run box - utilities in a folder in `PATH` can be started with just their file title from there. The expansion won't work fully if a user variable references another user variable, though.